# how to slide vertical menu jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i've been tried to create a vertical slide menu with css and jquery but have no luck.
how can i get each click item menu in jquery?

from my ul class="flyoutFirst".

each class="flyoutFirst" has own items link like in the markup.

thank you for teaching me.

here is the example jquery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.list li').click(function() {
    $('.list').animate({
      left: '-100%'
    });
    return false;
  })

  $('.back').click(function() {
    $('.list').animate({
      left: '0'
    });
  })

});
```

more details:
[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/giantape/2ph8mzgd/4/)

best regards,

ape

Answer (score 0):

tried the the link and i think its working fine, Please do emphasize your question clearly. What do you want to

Comment: hi @reside thanks for the answer. basicly i want to show  my ul class="flyoutFirst". now it just show me the last ul class="flyoutFirst" when i click the article.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don`t understand, what you want to do. But all information about your click event with nested elements you can get on this way:

```
$('.list li').click(function(e) {
console.log(e);
```

With "e" argument you can get all info.
https://jsfiddle.net/cfrd6mg9/

Comment: hi @Alexey sorry for the unclear questions. i want to show my each class="flyoutFirst" when i click the article.

Comment: sorry, but I dont understand, where your class should be contain

Answer (score 0):

ok finaly i found a solution.

maybe this is not a good solution but it is work!
in my js file:

```
    $(function() {
      $('.list li').click(function() {
        $('.list').animate({
          left: '-100%'
        });
        $(this).find('.flyoutFirst').css({display: 'block'});
        return false;
      })

      $('.back').click(function() {
        $('.list').animate({
          left: '0'
        }, function(){
           $(this).find('.flyoutFirst').css({display: 'none'});
        });
      })

    });
```

see my update at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/giantape/2ph8mzgd/6/)

and just add display: none in my class flyoutFirst in css.
hope that also help people very basic idea how to create a slide menu.
thank you all.

best regards,

ape